# ЧПУ в адресной строке результатов поиска

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, url, поиск, чпу

Понимаю, что это наверное не особо принципиально, но раз все url имеют опрятный вид, хотелось бы и этот привести к этакому «стандарту».

Форма находится в layout.php

```
<form method="get" action="/search/"> … </form>
```

В index.php есть такие правила для входящих запросов:

```
// Для вывода конкретной статьи, выводит, например: http://site.org/article/1
$router->addRoute('^/article/([0-9a-zA-Z\-]+)', function($url, $id) {
   article_action($id);
});

// Для поиска, выводит, например: http://site.org/search/?termin=Запрос
$router->addRoute('^/search/', function($url) {
    $termin = $_GET['termin'];
   search_action($termin);
});
```

А если попробовать вот так:

```
// Хотелось бы вот так: http://site.org/search/Запрос
$router->addRoute('^/search/([0-9a-zA-Z\-]+)', function($url, $termin) {
   category_action($termin);
```

то, не работает.

Подскажите пожалуйста, где может быть ошибка?

(регулярка не поддерживает кириллицу, но я пока не заморачиваюсь, это уже второе дело, использую запросы латинских терминов)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Непонятно, как рауты *на сервере* должны помочь с сылкой, которую отправляет *браузер*

Тут только два варианта: либо яваскриптом обрабатывать форму, либо делать как предлагали в прошлом вопросе - получать на сервере обычный вариант, и делать редирект на "опрятную ссылку".

Мне оба эти варианта кажутся куда более уродливыми, чем ссылка со знаком вопроса. Гугль вот не гнушается в своем поиске её использовать, [stack overflow - тоже](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA). Я думаю, что не так уж это "неэстетично"

Comment: Ну, в таком случае и я не буду чудить :)